# storing user values in an array then comparing these variables using bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

```
while read line

do

 if [ $line -ge $zero ]

 then 

 a+=($line)  ##here I am attempting to store the values in an array

 else 

  for i in ${a[@]}
  do

 echo $(a[$i]) ## here I am trying to print them


  done

 fi
```

what is going wrong? it is giving this error:

a[1]: command not found

a[2]: command not found

a[3]: command not found 
done

Comment: First thing , Learn to quote your variables. `$(a[$i])` is a command substituion, What are  you really trying to do? c

Comment: `for i in ${a[@]}` will iterate over the values in the array, not its indexes; that is, if the array is `a=(100 507 12)`, then `i` will be set to 100, then 507, then 12. So you want `echo "$i"` instead of `echo ${a[$i]}` (let alone `echo ${a[$i]}` which, as @Jetchisel pointed out, does something completely different).

Answer (score 1):

From the begining

```
if [ $line -ge $zero ]
```

what data type should be in `$line`?
`-ge` used in numeric comparison. If `$line` is a string than use `=` or if you just wnt to check that it's not empty use this syntax `if [[ "$line" ]]`
Next.

```
a+=($line)
```

Again if `$line` is a string then you should wrap in "" like this a+=("$line")
coz line can contain spaces.
For loop.

```
  for i in ${a[@]}
  do

 echo $(a[$i]) ## here I am trying to print them
```

You'r messing with syntax here `for i in ${a[@]}` will iterate over arrays values, not indexes. And again if values are strings use "" like this `for i in "${a[@]}"`
So this `echo $(a[$i])` won't work by 2 reasons. First you should use {} here, like this `echo ${a[$i]}`, second `$i` is not index, but it's may actualy work if it's a digit but in a wrong way. So here you need just `echo $i` coz `$i` is alredy a value from `a` array. Or rewrite foor loop.

```
for i in ${!a[@]}
do
    echo ${a[$i]} ## here I am trying to print them
done
```

And last but not least, there is no `done` at the end of this script or it's just a part? So in the and it should look like this.

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line ]]; then 
        a+=( "$line" )  ##here I am attempting to store the values in an array
    else 
        for i in ${!a[@]}; do
            echo ${a[$i]} ## here I am trying to print them
        done
    fi
done < data.txt
echo ${a[@]} # print rusult
```